# How to determine device type from Swift? (OS X or iOS)

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I know Swift is relatively new, but I was wondering if there was a way to determine the device type?

(Like you used to be able to do with a `#define`)?

Mainly I would like to know how to differentiate OS X or iOS.  I have found nothing on the subject.

Comment: You'd probably want to have two targets, one for your iOS app, and one for your OS X app.

Comment: Since Swift doesn't have a preprocessor nor macros, maybe you can use runtime checks.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

If you're building for both iOS and macOS (and maybe for watchOS and tvOS, too), you're compiling at least twice: once for each platform. If you want different code to execute on each platform, you want a build-time conditional, not a run-time check.

Swift has no preprocessor, but it does have conditional build directives — and for the most part, they look like the C equivalent.

```
#if os(iOS) || os(watchOS) || os(tvOS)
    let color = UIColor.red
#elseif os(macOS)
    let color = NSColor.red
#else
    println("OMG, it's that mythical new Apple product!!!")
#endif
```

You can also use build configurations to test for architecture (`x86_64`, `arm`, `arm64`, `i386`), Target environment (iOS simulator or Mac Catalyst), or `-D` compiler flags (including the `DEBUG` flag defined by the standard Xcode templates). Don’t assume that these things go together — Apple has announced macOS on arm64 to ship in 2020, so arm64 doesn’t imply iOS, and iOS Simulator doesn’t imply x86, etc.

See [Compiler Control statements](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#grammar_conditional-compilation-block) in *The Swift Programming Language*.

(If you want to distinguish which kind of iOS device you're on at runtime, use the `UIDevice` class just like you would from ObjC. It's typically more useful and safe to look at the device attributes that are important to you rather than a device name or idiom — e.g. use traits and size classes to lay out your UI, check Metal for the GPU capabilities you require, etc.)

Comment: +1 for the `else` case. Always handle edge cases! :-p

Comment: Note that it should be `#elseif os(macOS)` now according to the [Swift Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID539)

Comment: Does `iOS` include `iPadOS` here?

Comment: For all developer SDK concerns, iPadOS is iOS. If you need to detect whether an app built for both iPhone and iPad is currently running on iPad or iPhone, there are various ways to ask for that at runtime. (And the best way to detect this depends on what you want to use if for, so it's best asked as a separate stack overflow question.)

Answer (score 37):

This should provide you with every use case:

```
#if os(OSX)
    print("macOS")
#elseif os(watchOS)
    print("watchOS")
#elseif os(tvOS)
    print("tvOS")
#elseif os(iOS)
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        print("macOS - Catalyst")
    #else
        print("iOS")
    #endif
#endif
```

Comment: Has there been any updates regarding iPadOS? Or it's still recognised as iOS?

Comment: For iPad use if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad

Answer (score 12):

**Since Swift 4.2 you can replace**

```
#if os(iOS) || os(watchOS) || os(tvOS)
    let color = UIColor.redColor()
#elseif os(OSX)
    let color = NSColor.redColor()
#else
     println("OMG, it's that mythical new Apple product!!!")
#endif
```

**By**

```
#if canImport(UIKit)
    let color = UIColor.redColor()
#elseif os(OSX)
    let color = NSColor.redColor()
#else
    #error("OMG, it's that mythical new Apple product!!!")
#endif
```

Comment: @Cristik My answer was on Jun 11 2018, and the accepted answer was updated on Nov 3 2018! I updated the accepted answer but it wasn't approved!

Comment: Yeah, but the error message is present in that answer since it's first revision, from  Jun 5 '14. BTW, I was referring only to that message in particular, not to other aspects of the answer.

Comment: Before I answer that question, the accepted answer was #if canImport(UIKit), but after 4.2 the test has changed to #if os(iOS) || os(watchOS) || os(tvOS) this is the only part I changed

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24065534/1. `"OMG, it's that mythical new Apple product!!!"` is there. This is the text I'm talking about.

Comment: I don't think this will work anymore, now that macOS can, in fact, import UIKit as part of Mac Catalyst.

Answer (score 7):

Updating for Mac Catalyst. You may also now use the following to determine if iOS or Mac Catalyst:

```
let color: UIColor
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
color = .systemRed
#else
color = .systemBlue
#endif
```

For example.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me. `#if os(OSX)` does not work for Mac Catalyst

Answer (score 6):

### Swift 4 (updated Jul 21, 2020)

```swift
enum TargetDevice {
    case nativeMac
    case iPad
    case iPhone
    case iWatch
    
    public static var currentDevice: Self {
        var currentDeviceModel = UIDevice.current.model
        #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        currentDeviceModel = "nativeMac"
        #elseif os(watchOS)
        currentDeviceModel = "watchOS"
        #endif
        
        if currentDeviceModel.starts(with: "iPhone") {
            return .iPhone
        }
        if currentDeviceModel.starts(with: "iPad") {
            return .iPad
        }
        if currentDeviceModel.starts(with: "watchOS") {
            return .iWatch
        }
        return .nativeMac
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```swift
print(TargetDevice.currentDevice)
```

Comment: this will not work for the watch because UIKit is not available for them.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5** and **Xcode 13**

I you are using "Scale interface to Match iPad, you cannot use `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom` , because it will return an `.iPad` value. However it is recommended to use `targetEnvironment` instead. Here is example code:

```
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
            //execute your code for mac device
    #endif
```

If you are NOT using scale interface to Match iPad,but rather using "Optimize interface for mac" you can use this code for determning device:

```
UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .mac
```

Here is [apple documantation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst/choosing_a_user_interface_idiom_for_your_mac_app/) providing more info.

[image: mac project setup]

Answer (score -1):

```
var device = UIDevice.currentDevice().model
```

This code worked for me. I have implemented that on textfield and keyboard dismissing part. See below.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{

    print(device)

    if (textField.tag  == 1 && (device == "iPhone" || device == "iPhone Simulator" ))
    {
        var scrollPoint:CGPoint = CGPointMake(0,passwordTF.frame.origin.y/2);
        LoginScroll!.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true);
    }
    else if (textField.tag  == 2 && (device == "iPhone" || device == "iPhone Simulator"))
    {
        var scrollPoint:CGPoint = CGPointMake(0,passwordTF.frame.origin.y/1.3);
        LoginScroll!.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true);
    }

    return true

}
```

Comment: This is only for iOS, not macOS

Comment: In Swift 3: `UIDevice.current.model`