# Declare property only on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos, sprite-kit, cmmotionmanager

I am making a SpriteKit game for iOS, OSX, and tvOS. I am trying to use the accelerometer for my iOS target. I have the check for iOS on import of the CMMotionManager, but I can't seem to get the check to work when creating my motion manager property.

```
#if os(iOS)
    import CMMotionManager
#endif

class MainPlayScene: TCScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    //MARK: Properties
    //Motion
    @available(iOS 9, *) // Does not work, just trying things out....
    var motionManager:CMMotionManager {
        return motionManager
    }
```

How can I do this check?

EDIT: It is late here, and the more I think about it, correct me if I am on the wrong track all together. How can I use the accelerometer for iOS only and still share my scene code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the same syntax that you used for your import statement. This is also what apple does in their sample game DemoBots.

```
#if os(iOS)
var motionManager....
#endif

#if os(tvOS)
...
#endif
```

You can also do multiple checks and use else/else if

```
 #if os(iOS) || os(tvOS)
 .... 
 #elseif os(OSX)
 ... 
 #endif
 ... // Code for other platforms
 #endif
```

[How to determine device type from Swift? (OS X or iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065017/how-to-determine-device-type-from-swift-os-x-or-ios)

Just curious, any particular reason you make the motionManager property computed?

Comment: No reason, I was just trying different things to see if they would work. Great solution, thanks.

Comment: Awesome. Happy coding

Comment: Incase you wonder, this seems to be the correct way (you asked if you are on the wrong track). Apple is also doing it this way in their sample game DemoBots.

Comment: oh great! I have looked at DemoBots a while ago, but I guess I will need to look at it again. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, i just updated my answer with some more detail. DemoBots is well worth to check out properly. Its quite complex but you can pick it apart bit by bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    import CMMotionManager
```